# Assert.Fail failed. System.NotSupportedException: GetProperty of "HasFocus" is not supported on control type: Window

Tags: c#, firefox, coded-ui-tests, notsupportedexception

I am trying to run my Coded UI test in FireFox browser and getting an error message:

> Assert.Fail failed. System.NotSupportedException: GetProperty of "HasFocus" is not supported on control type: Window

I am trying to run my Coded UI test in FireFox browser and getting an error message:

> Assert.Fail failed. System.NotSupportedException: GetProperty of "HasFocus" is not supported on control type: Window

```
    private void NewHouseCalcTest(Action<test.Web.Testing.Utility> testGroup)
    {
        DataRow dr = TestContext.DataRow;
        Assertions assert = new Assertions(TestContext);

        NewHouseUIMapClasses.LoadNewHouseUrlParams win = this.NewHouseUIMap.LoadNewHouseUrlParams;

        win.UINewHouseCalculatorHoWindowUrl = Common.GetParamValue(dr, "NewHouseUrl", win.UINewHouseCalculatorHoWindowUrl);



        if (Common.IsIterationEnabled(TestContext.DataRow))
        {
            using (test.Web.Testing.Utility util = new test.Web.Testing.Utility(TestContext, 2000, TestContext.ResultsDirectory))
            {

                // The following entries set the browser, either Internet Explorer or Firefox and whether or not to clear cookies and/or cache
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(BrowserWindow.CurrentBrowser))
                {
                    BrowserWindow.CurrentBrowser = "Internet Explorer";
                }
                BrowserWindow.ClearCache();
                BrowserWindow.ClearCookies();

                // If we have a test case associated with this test, grab the data from the parameters

                // Populate the PageName and BrowserWindow of the util class
                util.PageName = this.NewHouseUIMap.LoadNewHouseUrlParams.UINewHouseCalculatorHoWindowUrl;
                util.BrowserWindow = this.NewHouseUIMap.UINewHouseCalculatorHoWindow;

                try
                {
                    util.RunTestStep("OpenNewHouseCalc", "Open NewHouse Calc Home Page ", () => this.NewHouseUIMap.LoadNewHouseUrl(), 5000);

                    testGroup(util);
                    util.CloseCurrentBrowser();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Assert.Fail(e.ToString());
                }
                finally
                {
                    util.CloseBrowserWindows();
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

[DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.TestCase","http://tfs.test.com:8080/tfs/enterprise;Microsoft .Net", "12004", DataAccessMethod.Sequential), TestMethod]

// Method to verify if textboxes are empty then error message shuould be visible in new house calculator.

```
    public void NewHouseWithoutVal()
    {

        Action<test.Web.Testing.Utility> testGroup = util =>
        {
            Assertions assert = new Assertions(TestContext);

            // Grabbing values from test case manager into dr.
            DataRow dr = TestContext.DataRow;

            NewHouseUIMapClasses.ClickCalculateParams TextBoxVal = this.NewHouseUIMap.ClickCalculateParams;

            // Grabbing values from dr into variables.
            TextBoxVal.UIWagesEditText = Common.GetParamValue(dr, "Wages", "");
            TextBoxVal.UIInvestmentsDividendsEditText = Common.GetParamValue(dr, "Investments", "");

           #region Variable Declarations
            HtmlDiv loanPageHeading = this.NewHouseUIMap.UINewHouseCalculatorHoWindow.UINewHouseCalculatorHoDocument1.LoanPageHeading;
            HtmlSpan wagesMessage = this.NewHouseUIMap.UINewHouseCalculatorHoWindow.UINewHouseCalculatorHoDocument1.UINewhousePane.WagesMessage;
            HtmlSpan investmentMessage = this.NewHouseUIMap.UINewHouseCalculatorHoWindow.UINewHouseCalculatorHoDocument1.UINewhousePane.InvestmentMessage;
            #endregion

            // Method to click on "Calculate" button.
            util.RunTestStep("ClkCalculate", "Click Calculate Button without value", () => this.NewHouseUIMap.ClickCalculate(), 5000);

            // Assertion to verify header page text and empty textboxes error messages.
            assert.AreEqual("Mortgage calculator - How much house can you afford?", loanPageHeading.InnerText);
            assert.AreEqual("This field is required.", wagesMessage.InnerText);
            assert.AreEqual("This field is required.", investmentMessage.InnerText);
          };

        NewHouseCalcTest(testGroup);
    }

    [DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.TestCase", "http://tfs.test.com:8080/tfs/enterprise;Microsoft .Net", "12041", DataAccessMethod.Sequential), TestMethod]
    public void NewHouseWithoutValFF()
    {
        BrowserWindow.CurrentBrowser = "Firefox";
        NewHouseWithoutVal();

    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. Show your work first. Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Comment: Also format the code properly